# How do I implement code to search word in a Trie?

Tags: java, tree, trie, huffman-code

**Code: Search word in Trie**

Implement the function **SearchWord** for the Trie class.
For a Trie, write the function for searching a word. Return true if the word is found successfully, otherwise return false.

***Note:** main function is given for your reference which we are using internally to test the code.*

**class TrieNode{**

```
char data;
boolean isTerminating;
TrieNode children[];
int childCount;

public TrieNode(char data) {
    this.data = data;
    isTerminating = false;
    children = new TrieNode[26];
    childCount = 0;
}
```

**}**

**public class Trie {**

```
private TrieNode root;
public int count;
public Trie() {
    root = new TrieNode('\0');
    count = 0;
}   

private boolean add(TrieNode root, String word){
    if(word.length() == 0){
        if (!root.isTerminating) {
            root.isTerminating = true;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }       
    int childIndex = word.charAt(0) - 'a';
    TrieNode child = root.children[childIndex];
    if(child == null){
        child = new TrieNode(word.charAt(0));
        root.children[childIndex] = child;
        root.childCount++;
    }
    return add(child, word.substring(1));

}

public void add(String word){
    if (add(root, word)) {
        this.count++;
    }
}

public boolean search(String word){
    // add your code here
    return search(root,word);
}
private boolean search(TrieNode root, String word){
    if(word.length()==0){
        return true;
    }
    int childIndex = word.charAt(0) -'a';
    TrieNode child = root.children[childIndex];
    if(child==null){
        return false;
    }
    return search(child, word.substring(1));
}
```

**}**

//Main Function
`code`

**import java.io.*;**

```
public class Runner {

static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Trie t = new Trie();
    String[] string = br.readLine().split("\\s");
    int choice = Integer.parseInt(string[0]);
    String word = "Null";
    if (string.length!=1)        
    {
        word = string[1];
    }
            
    while(choice != -1) {
        switch(choice) {
            case 1 : // insert
                t.add(word);
                break;
            case 2 : // search
                System.out.println(t.search(word));
                break;
            default :
                    return;
        }
        string = br.readLine().split("\\s");
        choice = Integer.parseInt(string[0]);
        if (string.length!=1)
        {
            word = string[1];
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the `isTerminating` information. In `search`, change:

```
    if(word.length()==0){
        return true;
    }
```

To:

```
    if(word.length()==0){
        return root.isTerminating;
    }
```